# SQL command to rename shows

Tags: mysql, replace, find

I wonder if someone can help with and SQL command to find and replace

I have a MYSQL database with names of shows
table one has the name of the episode

```
    Arrow - S1E9 - Year's End
    Arrow - S1E10 - Burned
    Arrow - S1E20 - Home Invasion
```

How would i go about renaming the episodes to look like this
Basically adding 0's to all seasons and adding 0's to all episodes up to 9 but not after 10 etc

```
    Arrow - S01E09 - Year's End
    Arrow - S01E10 - Burned
    Arrow - S01E20 - Home Invasion
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? If less than 8, what  third party regular expression library have you installed?

Comment: Please provide your table structure

Comment: Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: table goes like, id,display_name,folder_location, etc etc i just want to change the display_name field only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 8 that supports REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
UPDATE table SET name = REGEXP_REPLACE(name, 'E([1-9]) ', 'E0$1 ')
```

On earlier that doesn't support regex and no third party regex lib installed:

```
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E1 ', 'E01 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E2 ', 'E02 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E3 ', 'E03 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E4 ', 'E04 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E5 ', 'E05 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E6 ', 'E06 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E7 ', 'E07 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E8 ', 'E08 ')
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, 'E9 ', 'E09 ')
```

You could chain those replace and do it in one statement, but i feel like this is a one time or seldom run operation so absolute performance is less important than readable maintainable code

Chained would look like:

```
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, 'E9 ', 'E09 '), 'E8 ', 'E08 '), 'E7 ', 'E07 '), 'E6 ', 'E06 '), 'E5 ', 'E05 '), 'E4 ', 'E04 '), 'E3 ', 'E03 '), 'E2 ', 'E02 '), 'E1 ', 'E01 ')
```

Ugh!

The same advice follows for seasons, just switch the E for an S. If you're hoping to do it all in one regex statement:

```
UPDATE table SET name = REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '([ES])([1-9]) ', '$10$2 ')
```

Regex works like:

```
([ES])([1-8]) 
--locate an E or an S, store it in variable $1; 1 because it is the first pair of ( brackets ) in the expression
--immediately followed by a single digit 1 to 9, store in variable 2 (second pair of brackets)
--replace with variable1+'0'+variable2, so E7 -> E07
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with out regex is:

```
select CONCAT(SUBSTRING(COD, 1, 1), -- HERE GET 'S'
       0, -- HERE PUT '0'
       SUBSTRING(COD, 3, 1), -- HERE GET 'E'
       LPAD(SUBSTRING(COD, 4, 2),2,0) -- HERE PUT '0' IF ONLY ONE CHAR
) from (
select 'S1E9' AS COD
union all
select 'S1E10' AS R2
union all
select 'S1E20' AS R3) t
```

Can be more simple to understand.